# How can I fix a problem with Sessions being lost after suspend or hibernate?

Tags: gnome, 19.04, session

When I either sleep, suspend or hibernate and then resume, after logging back in my session is gone.

How can I debug this issue and is anyone else experiencing this issue?

I was not having this problem till I upgraded to 19.04.

Any help would be great as it's becoming a real pain.

Answer (score 0):

After investigating for several months I fix it adding "acpi_sleep=nonvs" boot parameter to kernel:

**1)** Edit file `/etc/default/grub` (superuser) and add `acpi_sleep=nonvs` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line, example:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet scsi_mod.scan=sync"
```

**2)** Execute: `update-grub2` (superuser).

**3)** Reboot and test it.